# Microsoft Graph: /sites?select=siteCollection,webUrl&filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null returns "Cannot enumerate sites"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Got error with call: /sites?select=siteCollection,webUrl&filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null

```
"error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "Cannot enumerate sites",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "f73vvv65-d20e-xxx-ae30-829d46a981d6",
        "date": "2019-10-24T17:17:03"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there Aaron. It would be helpful to add a bit more context to your question, especially in the title

Comment: It was an issue in Graph service side. Microsoft has fixed and it works now.

Comment: @Aaron It is not an issue in Graph service side. The endpoint you were trying to use was invalid. See my answer for clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to go through this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). There is a typo with the request you are trying to make. `$select` and `$filter` are query options and hence, you'll have to use the following endpoint to obtain the desired result.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?$select=siteCollection,webUrl&$filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null
```

Observe carefully that there is a `$` sign before the `filter` query option.